# Import Git repo with signed commits into Launchpad

Tags: git, github, bazaar, launchpad

I need to import [this GitHub repository](https://github.com/supertuxkart/stk-code) with signed commits into Launchpad to build packages for [this PPA](https://launchpad.net/~stk/+archive/ubuntu/daily).

A direct import will not work, due to [this bzr-git bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bzr-git/+bug/1084403), but a fast-export/fast-import is a workaround, according to https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bzr-git/+bug/1084403/comments/9.

I want to use my Raspberry Pi, which runs 24/7 as a web server, to make the conversion to `bzr` using fast-export/fast-import then have Launchpad automatically import it.

What is the best way to do this?

The conversion needs to be able to be run as a cron job, and the converted repository needs to be able to be imported by Launchpad automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is no longer an issue because, as of November 2016, Lauchpad supports [direct git-to-git code imports](http://blog.launchpad.net/code/git-to-git-imports) and mirroring of `git` repositories hosted elsewhere. Simply [mirror/import](https://help.launchpad.net/Code/Git#Mirroring_repositories_from_other_sites) via `git` instead of `bzr` and everything will be copied across, signed commits and all.

Answer (score 0):

> What is the best way to do this?

What i suggest to do is to fork the repository to your github account, once the repository is cloned (or even before) you can download as ZIP.

This will download the latest code as zip and not as `.git` repository.

This way you can bypass the bug which you mentioned above since now you are simply downloading ZIP and not git repository with signed commits.

[image]

Comment: But it needs to be able to imported automatically into Launchpad.